# cleaning rectangular

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a function in script that draws a rectangular on canvas.I want to clean the rectangular drew in the "if" condition.
I also have text on the canvas(its coordinates are 0,80) and it shouldn't be cleaned. Only the rectangular must be cleaned.

```
function red_stroke_2(yy) 
{ 
    //Red color edges
    context.strokeStyle = "#f00";
    context.strokeRect(0,yy,800,40);
}
 if (Option1==answers[qnumber])
{
     red_stroke_2(80);
}
```

Comment: context.clearrect ? is that waht u trying?

Answer (score 0):

Canvas is "stateless" in the sense that it does not know about the primitives that have been drawn or the calls that have been made. As such it is impossible to undo only a certain drawing call. If you need to modify the drawing, you need to redraw all of the items that you don't want to change. Of course you have the option to change single pixels, so if your text is black and the rectangle is red, you can replace all red pixels, but this won't work so good if antialiasing is enabled and is utterly complicated.

So either redraw the whole area (omit the rectangle drawing but render the text). Or consider using 2 Canvases on top of each other (one with the text, one with the background), then of course you can rerender the background without having to worry about the text.

Last but not least using SVG might be also an alternative, since this is stateful and consists of DOM elements that you can modify/insert/remove and the browser will do the compositing. In that case you would have a `rect` element and a `text`element and you could simply remove the former.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sebastian. That gives me a new idea.

Answer (score 0):

This will put transparent pixels instead of your rectangle:

```
function clean_red_stroke(yy)
{
    context.clearRect(0,yy,800,40);
}
//Call it with the same 'yy' you used in the drawing method
clean_red_stroke(80);
```

However I think you code could be improved, by using more variables (and consequently a most generic function) for exemple.